# Unable to Login to the application from local server using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm ABLE to Login to the application from client computer with jmeter configuration as shown
in picture but unable to the login to the application from local server with SAME jmeter configuration as shown in pic.What might be the reason.Please,
suggest me with your valueable clues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add a cookie manager? It's mandatory for authentication

Comment: Yes you are right . I happened to miss Cookie Manager on local server. Thanks alot for your response.